# How to read incoming messages on iPhone by an app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, imessage

I'm developing an app for android & iOS,However i developed an android app that reads incoming sms but don't developed for iOS yet.
Is it possible to read incoming sms on iPhone because whatsapp reads otp & auto filled,Moreover truecaller can read all incoming messages & detects otp from sms how it's possible?

Comment: Hi @parthiv, you can't read all sms in iPhone. You can only read OTP from the sms you just need to change the type of the textfield to OTP, it will automatically read the  OTP from the latest message.

Comment: @IleshP You should make that an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Truecaller definitely can't read all incoming messages.  It implements a message filtering and spam reporting extension which allows it to receive the sender details of messages

Comment: According to app requirement i need a sms content in app regardless of app state,Is it possible in iOS because same functionality i developed in android app?

Comment: OK, so how do apps such as SMS Export exist then?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to autofill a passcode field from an incoming message. There are a few steps you need to go through:

1. Create a `apple-app-site-association` file with a `webcredentials` key and upload to your server's `.well-known` directory.
2. Add the associated domains entitlement to your app
3. Add a `TextField` to your app with the correct content type:

```
TextField("Enter passcode", text: $passcode)
    .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
```

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains) for more details.

There's a useful guide [here](https://medium.com/mobilepeople/ios-password-autofill-how-and-why-b8414e6ada96).